# Áudio diferente em cada slide do carrossel bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com bootstrap e estou usando o carrossel dele, mas esse carrossel tem texto e vai ter áudio diferente em cada slide, mas não quero fazer com clique em cada indicador e sim ele reconhecer quando a classe active estiver em determinado slide, segue o exemplo o código que fiz.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="0" class="desbloquear active somslide1"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="1" class="desbloquear somslide2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="2" class="desbloquear somslide3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="3" class="desbloquear somslide4"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators3" data-slide-to="4" class="desbloquear somslide5"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <p>texto</p>
      <div class="audio2"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.somslide2').on('click',function(){
    $('.audio2').html('<audio id="som1" autoplay><source src="audio/CIPA.wav" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe de carrossel do Bootstrap expõe dois eventos para se conectar à funcionalidade do carrossel. Ambos os eventos têm as seguintes propriedades adicionais:

- direction: A direção na qual o carrossel está deslizando ("esquerda" ou "direita").
- relatedTarget: O elemento DOM que está sendo deslizado no lugar como o item ativo.
- from: O índice do item atual.
- to: O índice do próximo item.

Um dos eventos é slide.bs.carousel que é acionado imediatamente quando o método da instância do slide é chamado. Ou seja, toda vez que acontecer o "deslizamento" esse evento será disparado.

Assim, basta você pegar esse evento e tratar qual som deverá ser disparado de acordo com o parâmetro from:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (props) {
  // props.relatedTarget é a .carousel-item ativa  naquele momento.

  $('audio', props.relatedTarget).play(); // ou algo assim...
  // na linha acima estamos acessando a tag audio que está dentro da .carousel-item ativa naquele momento.

});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não deu certo, pois ele não reconhece play como função

Comment: Por isso eu disse "// ou algo assim"... Pois você já está acessando o objeto, agora vc só precisa dar o play.. aí é com vc.. ja que não tenho seu codigo... né?

Se quiser.. posta num JS BIN da vida e mostra pra mim o seu codigo e eu tento te ajudar.